# A collection sorted in Laravel is suddenly no longer sorted in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

In Laravel I have a simple Model named "Garbage", its migration looks like this:

```
Schema::create('garbages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->date('disposal_at');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

In my Laravel router (web.php) the routing looks like this:

```
Route::get('/garbage', function() {
    $garbages = \App\Models\Garbage::all()
        ->sortBy('disposal_at');

    // dd($garbage);

    return Inertia::render('Grabage', [
        'garbages' => $garbages
    ]);
});
```

As you can see i just get all my Garbage records, sort them by 'disposal_at' and pass it to `Inertia::render`.

Now I want to display the all records in a list via vue, the file looks like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    interface Garbage {
        id: number,
        disposal_at: string
    }

    const props = defineProps<{
        garbages: Garbage[]
    }>();
</script>

<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="garbage in garbages" :key="garbage.id">
            {{ garbage.disposal_at }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

The output looks like this:

- 2002-08-19
- 2002-06-05
- 1995-07-18
- 1978-12-21
- 1989-07-12
- 1975-09-06
- 2000-03-01
- 2012-06-04
- 2022-11-09
- 2006-04-10

Now my problem is, although I sorted the collection in laravel by "disposal_at", after i pass it via `Inertia::render()` to vue it is sorted by id again.

I have already had the values displayed via `dd($garbage)` in the laravel router to see if it is sorted there and that gives me the collection sorted by "disposal_at" but in Vue its not sorted by "disposal_at" anymore.

Why does that happen and how do i fix it?

Comment: How about also doing `'garbages' => $garbages->values()` to reset the array indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you need to reset the keys after sorting, using the `values()` method:

```
$garbages = \App\Models\Garbage::all()
    ->sortBy('disposal_at')
    ->values();
```

When you serialize collection and sent to the frontend, JS do not guarantee order. With `values()` you preserve order.